# Update location only once

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I am adding a mapKit for my app, and I setting the middle of the map to be the persons current location, in lat and lng.  I am able to get it working, however, it keeps updating every so often.  I only want it to update once when the app is loaded, then not update anymore.  Maybe update every 2 minutes.  Here is my code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation = locations.last as! CLLocation


    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latestLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.015, 0.015)

    //Let our point be the center of our span
    //region holds value of span and location
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    //set up region on mapView
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //MKPointAnnotation defines a concrete annotation
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are targeting only iOS 9, look at the new `requestLocation()` method. It addresses your problem. If you need to target older versions of iOS, you could add `stopMonitoringLocation()` to the

```
func locationManager(
    manager: CLLocationManager!, 
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!
)
```

This will stop the monitoring once you get one reading...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your starting you location manager with, but I think you might want to look at using:

```
startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

to start your location manager. Here is apple's documentation on the subject: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges